# How to replace the first dimension of a 3D numpy array with values from a 1D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I've got a 3D and a 1D numpy array- A sized (3750, 17, 1000) and B sized (3750). I want to replace the values in the 1st dimension of A with the values from array B, so that the resulting array C is still sized (3750, 17, 1000), but the values in the first dimension are different.

```
>>> A.shape
(3750, 17, 1000)

>>> B.shape (3750,)

>>> C.shape(3750, 17, 1000)
```

I've tried:

```
>>> C = np.concatenate((A, np.broadcast_to(np.array(B)[:, None, None],A.shape)), axis = 0)
```

But the output is:

```
>>> C.shape (7500, 17, 1000)
```

So basically if

A =

```
1 [x, y ... 1000]

  [x, y ... 1000]

  ...17

2 [x, y ... 1000]

  [x, y ... 1000]

  ...17

3 [x, y ... 1000]

  [x, y ... 1000]

  ...17
.
.
.
3750
```

and B =

```
22
43
11
.
.
n=3750
```

Then C should look like

```
22 [x, y ... 1000]
   [x, y ... 1000]
    ...17

43 [x, y ... 1000]
   [x, y ... 1000]
    ...17

11 [x, y ... 1000]
   [x, y ... 1000]
    ...17
.
.
.
n=3750
```

Comment: Do you want the values for B for all other dimensions? So C[:,0,0] == C[:,0,1] == C[:,1,0] ... ? To your output: concatenate adds the 3750 values of B to the existing 3750, so axis=0 ends up with size 7500.

Comment: It's a bit unclear. Do you want: `A = C.copy()` and then `A[:, 0, 0] = B`. What do you mean by "the value in the first dimension" of A. For me it means A[:, 0, 0] ?

Comment: No, I just want to change the first dimension in A with values of B. The other 2 dimensions in A should stay as they are.

Comment: But the first dimension is repeated in all other dimensions. Do you want to change [:,0,0] or do you want to have B for all other dimensions as well? I have a feeling that you are not quite aware of the meaning of dimensions. You cannot change the values of "one dimension". You can change the values of one dimension for all given other dimensions.

Comment: Imagine your problem as a cube with data in it. Now the cube is given one row of data. You need to specify where to put it. Right in the middle? Top left? Top right? Anywhere in between?

Comment: I updated the post and tried to explain what I mean. Sorry for the messy explanation, I hope it's understandable.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand the structure of the array. What does `A = 1 [x, y, ... 1000]` mean?

Comment: Give a smaller example, such as (4,2,3) and (4,) shapes.  or even make `A` 2d.

Comment: So basically I want to replace the index values 0-3749 in array A with the values from array B (which has a length of 3750). So if A=[[0, x, x], [1, x, x], [2, x, x], [3, x, x]] and B=[22, 43, 11, 59], then I'd want C = [[22, x, x], [43, x, x], [11, x, x], [59, x, x]]. Therefore I called it "change the value in the first dimension (of a 3-dimensional array), which I guess is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
A[:,0,0] = B
```

Is it correct?